# Filtering with XPath removes selected Value in ComboBox that is bind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, combobox

I have the following setup:

This is the main screen:

```
    <ListView Name="lineData" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=LineInformation, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}" PreviewMouseUp="lineData_PreviewMouseUp" SelectedIndex="0" 
              Foreground="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView  x:Name="gridViewItems" AllowsColumnReorder="false">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Product" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ComboBox Name="descriptionComboBox" Loaded="description_Loaded"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Product}" SourceUpdated="descriptionComboBox_SourceUpdated"
                                    MinWidth="200" Width="Auto" SelectionChanged="description_SelectionChanged" TargetUpdated="descriptionComboBox_TargetUpdated">
                                  <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource XmlFile}" />
                                  </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>                            
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

This screen has a button, that calls a new window like this:

```
        Window newWindow = new Window();
        buildWindow.Owner = this; //MainWindow is the owner
        buildWindow.ShowDialog();
```

This new Window filters out the values that are in the combo box from the first window like this:

```
        XmlDataProvider provider = Owner.FindResource("XmlFile") as XmlDataProvider;
        provider.XPath = _configuration.CreateFilterQuery();
        provider.Refresh();
```

So the combobox has a binding to this XmlFile. The problem I have is that now I need to keep the value displayed on the comboboxes if they belong under category of the new filter.

But when I call the .Refresh() function the combobox's selected index is reset.

Any ideas how to maintain the displayed text after applying the XPath query?

Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried to remember the selection before the Refresh, and then check if the value still exists after the new filter and select it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your child window will have to have it's own XmlDataProvider.  Maybe do something like this?

```
        XmlDataProvider provider = Owner.FindResource("XmlFile") as XmlDataProvider;
        XDocument cloneDoc = new XDocument(provider.Document);

        XmlDataProvider childProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
        childProvider.Document = cloneDoc;
        childProvider.XPath = _configuration.CreateFilterQuery();
        childProvider.Refresh();

        Window newWindow = new Window();
        newWindow.Provider = childProvider;
        newWindow.Owner = this; //MainWindow is the owner
        newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

You'd have to subclass window and add that Provider property.  You could alternatively create an XDocument property and just bind everything in the child window.